# OpenID URL, StackOverflow automatically adds '/index.html', what if 'index.html' changes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, openid, login, hyperlinks

I entered my OpenID URL, but after I've logged into OpenID (at my provider's site) and approved of StackOverflow, I was redirected to StackOverflow and it used this as the OpenID URL:

**`<my entered URL>/index.html`**

I don't think this is correct, since the moment I change my site to have a frontpage other than 'index.html' I can't log into StackOverflow anymore.

To clarify: the site - because of the webserver - shows the content of index.html, since there was no page specified. But that's no reason for stackoverflow to use '.../index.html' as OpenID URL. I know some other sites (and API's) that don't have this behavior and I think it's not really desirable to have this.

It might also be interesting to know that OpenID definition on the site is a delegate that refers to my real provider URL, so maybe it has something to do with that.

Comment: Did you create the webpage?

Comment: As explained in my clarification: the site is my own, it uses the delegate link (OpenID 1.1 ... I think) to refer to my OpenID provider.

Comment: I'm doing the same thing - but i don't get a redirect. You shouldn't need one either, your server should just serve index.html when the directory is requested. Check that you haven't inadvertently configured URL rewrite rules... perhaps out of a desire to standardize on `example.com/index.html` URLs for normal links?

Comment: Well, I haven't yet made a decent site, so I've not done anything "out of the ordinary" (except put a index.html on the server).
It's hosted by a typical hosting company, so they've probably configured nothing special.
And if I go to the site myself, there is not rewrite done, I just see the domain name, and no page name behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your website's root url is returning a `Content-Location` header:

```
Content-Location: http://yoursite/index.html
```

From the [w3.org http/1.1 protocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html):

> The value of Content-Location also defines the base URI for the entity.

I don't know if that header is really needed for your root - try removing it and we can fix your OpenID on the sites!

Comment: Thanks for the remark, it got me thinking.
I discovered that for some weird reason, the webserver first gives a lot of crud and a HTTP 302 code (Object moved) and that's probably why SO added '/index.html'.
That's their "way" of getting the default webpage.
I'll have to fix that before my OpenID URL can be corrected.

Comment: You could also try another OpenID provider, to see if they sniff that header.

Comment: Also, know that you can add an "alternate" OpenID to your profile from your User page - you can test your website's issue by adding another OpenID.  If you get the interstitial page "Associate OpenID," you know that your site/provider is returning a different OpenID.

Answer (score 1):

Uh, I'd guess it's *your site* redirecting to `index.html`... SO certainly doesn't mess with mine!